# npm run Lifecycle scripts included in project: test echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, react-native

I am trying to develop a springboot/react app and have installed react and created the react project. However when I try to execute:

```
npm run
```

I get the following error:

```
Lifecycle scripts included in project:
  test
    echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1
```

I also installed jest I believe and when I go to package.json:
I have changed the test: to "jest"

```
"scripts": {
 "start": "react-scripts start",
 "build": "react-scripts build",
 "test": "jest",
 "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

I also tried when it was just "react-scripts test" and that gave me the same error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm start` or `npm test`.